# CSS and JS not rendering from pub/static folder after installation of Magento 2.2.8

Tags: error, js-css, magento2.2.8

I have just installed Magento 2.2.8 and it throws an error on home page

[image: magento 2 homepage error]

then I ran following commands

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But its nothing changed how to solved this error? why Magento 2.2.8 does not taking pub/static path for images,css and js files?

Comment: Its looks like a permissions issue. Have you tried giving permission to var/, pub/?

Comment: I have installed magento in local. you can check screenshot

Comment: there is no need to run chmod command because my magento installed in xampp windows OS in local computer. I did not installed on server

Comment: This may be a issue because of .htaccess file.
Please check if there is .htaccess file under pub/static or not.

Comment: or try to rename .htaccess file from your magento rot directory then check if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

Around line 133 find function **isPathInDirectories**

add

`$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // extra code added`

like

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // extra code added
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome bro,it works fine,appreciated

Comment: @NirajPatel Thanks brother